# Why is Apache Hive XPath returning only first match?

Tags: xml, hadoop, xpath, hive

I need some help with XML using Hive.

I have a hive string column with XML content, and I need to return all the occurrences of a specific tag.

I'm using `xpath_string(columnname, '//tagname/text()')`, but it's returning only the first occurrence of the tag.

**Is it possible to return all tags in XML format?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the [Apache Hive documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+XPathUDF), rather than `xpath_string()`,

> **xpath_string**
>
> The `xpath_string()` function returns the text of the first matching
>   node.

use `xpath()`:

> **xpath**
>
> The `xpath()` function always returns a hive array of strings.

if you want more than the text of the first matching node.

Comment: Thanks kjhughes, I got this. Is there a way to break that array in many lines?

Comment: @RodrigoFerreira: You're welcome.  Please [**accept**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/234215) this answer if it's helped, and ask a new question, including what you've tried and how your results deviate from your expectations for any further follow-ups. 
 Thanks.